# How to merge publisher subscriber code in MQTT for ESP8266?

Tags: mqtt, esp8266

I am new to ESP8266 & MQTT. Recently I am trying to merge two separate codes for publisher & subscriber in MQTT so that my ESP8266 can publish and subscribe at the same time to different topics. AS far as I have tried they never work when merged but work separately.
Please guide me as to how I can merge them or if there is a merged code available then please share.

**Publisher Code:**

```
#include <Bounce2.h> // Used for "debouncing" the pushbutton
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> // Enables the ESP8266 to connect to the local network (via WiFi)
#include <PubSubClient.h> // Allows us to connect to, and publish to the MQTT broker

const int ledPin = 0; // This code uses the built-in led for visual feedback that the button has been pressed
const int buttonPin = 13; // Connect your button to pin #13

// WiFi
// Make sure to update this for your own WiFi network!
const char* ssid = "TP-LINK_7224";
const char* wifi_password = "RFID7890";

// MQTT
// Make sure to update this for your own MQTT Broker!
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.71.107";
const char* mqtt_topic = "Flash_Message";
const char* mqtt_username = "pi";
const char* mqtt_password = "pi123";
// The client id identifies the ESP8266 device. Think of it a bit like a hostname (Or just a name, like Greg).
const char* clientID = "ESP01";

// Initialise the Pushbutton Bouncer object
Bounce bouncer = Bounce();

// Initialise the WiFi and MQTT Client objects
WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient client(mqtt_server, 1883, wifiClient); // 1883 is the listener port for the Broker

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  // Switch the on-board LED off to start with
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

  // Setup pushbutton Bouncer object
  bouncer.attach(buttonPin);
  bouncer.interval(5);

  // Begin Serial on 115200
  // Remember to choose the correct Baudrate on the Serial monitor!
  // This is just for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  // Connect to the WiFi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, wifi_password);

  // Wait until the connection has been confirmed before continuing
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  // Debugging - Output the IP Address of the ESP8266
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Connect to MQTT Broker
  // client.connect returns a boolean value to let us know if the connection was successful.
  // If the connection is failing, make sure you are using the correct MQTT Username and Password (Setup Earlier in the Instructable)
  if (client.connect(clientID, mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) {
    Serial.println("Connected to MQTT Broker!");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection to MQTT Broker failed...");
  }

}

void loop() {
  // Update button state
  // This needs to be called so that the Bouncer object can check if the button has been pressed
  bouncer.update();

  if (bouncer.rose()) {
    // Turn light on when button is pressed down
    // (i.e. if the state of the button rose from 0 to 1 (not pressed to pressed))
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

    // PUBLISH to the MQTT Broker (topic = mqtt_topic, defined at the beginning)
    // Here, "Button pressed!" is the Payload, but this could be changed to a sensor reading, for example.
    if (client.publish(mqtt_topic, "Button pressed!")) {
      Serial.println("Button pushed and message sent!");
    }
    // Again, client.publish will return a boolean value depending on whether it succeded or not.
    // If the message failed to send, we will try again, as the connection may have broken.
    else {
      Serial.println("Message failed to send. Reconnecting to MQTT Broker and trying again");
      client.connect(clientID, mqtt_username, mqtt_password);
      delay(10); // This delay ensures that client.publish doesn't clash with the client.connect call
      client.publish(mqtt_topic, "Button pressed!");
    }
  }
  else if (bouncer.fell()) {
    // Turn light off when button is released
    // i.e. if state goes from high (1) to low (0) (pressed to not pressed)
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
}
```

**Subscriber Code:**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> // Enables the ESP8266 to connect to the local network (via WiFi)
#include <PubSubClient.h> // Allows us to connect to, and publish to the MQTT broker

const int ledPin = 16; // This code uses the built-in led for visual feedback that a message has been received

// WiFi
// Make sure to update this for your own WiFi network!
const char* ssid = "TP-LINK_7224";
const char* wifi_password = "RFID7890";

// MQTT
// Make sure to update this for your own MQTT Broker!
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.71.127";
const char* mqtt_topic = "flash";
const char* mqtt_username = "pi";
const char* mqtt_password = "pi123";
// The client id identifies the ESP8266 device. Think of it a bit like a hostname (Or just a name, like Greg).
const char* clientID = "ESP01";

// Initialise the WiFi and MQTT Client objects
WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient client(mqtt_server, 1883, wifiClient); // 1883 is the listener port for the Broker

void ReceivedMessage(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  // Output the first character of the message to serial (debug)
  Serial.println((char)payload[0]);

  // Handle the message we received
  // Here, we are only looking at the first character of the received message (payload[0])
  // If it is 0, turn the led off.
  // If it is 1, turn the led on.
  if ((char)payload[0] == 'E' && (char)payload[1] == 'S' && (char)payload[2] == 'P' && (char)payload[3] == '0' && (char)payload[4] == '1' ) {

    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
    delay(4000);// Notice for the HUZZAH Pin 0, HIGH is OFF and LOW is ON. Normally it is the other way around.
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  if ((char)payload[0] == '0') {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
}

bool Connect() {
  // Connect to MQTT Server and subscribe to the topic
  if (client.connect(clientID, mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) {
      client.subscribe(mqtt_topic);
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  // Switch the on-board LED off to start with
//  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  // Begin Serial on 115200
  // Remember to choose the correct Baudrate on the Serial monitor!
  // This is just for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  // Connect to the WiFi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, wifi_password);

  // Wait until the connection has been confirmed before continuing
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  // Debugging - Output the IP Address of the ESP8266
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Connect to MQTT Broker
  // setCallback sets the function to be called when a message is received.
  client.setCallback(ReceivedMessage);
  if (Connect()) {
    Serial.println("Connected Successfully to MQTT Broker!");  
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection Failed!");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // If the connection is lost, try to connect again
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Connect();
  }
  // client.loop() just tells the MQTT client code to do what it needs to do itself (i.e. check for messages, etc.)
  client.loop();
  // Once it has done all it needs to do for this cycle, go back to checking if we are still connected.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works if you want to publish while subscribing.

```
/*
 * ESP8266 (Adafruit HUZZAH) Mosquitto MQTT Publish Example
 * Thomas Varnish (https://github.com/tvarnish), (https://www.instructables.com/member/Tango172)
 * Made as part of my MQTT Instructable - "How to use MQTT with the Raspberry Pi and ESP8266"
 */
#include <Bounce2.h> // Used for "debouncing" the pushbutton
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> // Enables the ESP8266 to connect to the local network (via WiFi)
#include <PubSubClient.h> // Allows us to connect to, and publish to the MQTT broker

const int ledPin = 0; // This code uses the built-in led for visual feedback that the button has been pressed
const int buttonPin = 13; // Connect your button to pin #13

// WiFi
// Make sure to update this for your own WiFi network!
const char* ssid = "TP-LINK_7224";
const char* wifi_password = "RFID7890";

// MQTT
// Make sure to update this for your own MQTT Broker!
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.58.117";
const char* mqtt_topic = "Flash_Message";
const char* mqtt_topic_sub = "flash";
const char* mqtt_username = "pi";
const char* mqtt_password = "pi123";
// The client id identifies the ESP8266 device. Think of it a bit like a hostname (Or just a name, like Greg).
const char* clientID = "ESP01";

// Initialise the Pushbutton Bouncer object
Bounce bouncer = Bounce();

// Initialise the WiFi and MQTT Client objects
WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient client(mqtt_server, 1883, wifiClient); // 1883 is the listener port for the Broker

void ReceivedMessage(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  // Output the first character of the message to serial (debug)
  Serial.println((char)payload[0]);

  // Handle the message we received
  // Here, we are only looking at the first character of the received message (payload[0])
  // If it is 0, turn the led off.
  // If it is 1, turn the led on.
  if ((char)payload[0] == 'E' && (char)payload[1] == 'S' && (char)payload[2] == 'P' && (char)payload[3] == '0' && (char)payload[4] == '1' ) {

    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
    delay(4000);// Notice for the HUZZAH Pin 0, HIGH is OFF and LOW is ON. Normally it is the other way around.
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  if ((char)payload[0] == '0') {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  // Switch the on-board LED off to start with
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

  // Setup pushbutton Bouncer object
  bouncer.attach(buttonPin);
  bouncer.interval(5);

  // Begin Serial on 115200
  // Remember to choose the correct Baudrate on the Serial monitor!
  // This is just for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  // Connect to the WiFi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, wifi_password);

  // Wait until the connection has been confirmed before continuing
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  // Debugging - Output the IP Address of the ESP8266
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
client.setCallback(ReceivedMessage);
  // Connect to MQTT Broker
  // client.connect returns a boolean value to let us know if the connection was successful.
  // If the connection is failing, make sure you are using the correct MQTT Username and Password (Setup Earlier in the Instructable)
  if (client.connect(clientID, mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) {
    client.subscribe(mqtt_topic_sub);
    Serial.println("Connected to MQTT Broker!");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection to MQTT Broker failed...");
  }

}

bool Connect() {
  // Connect to MQTT Server and subscribe to the topic
  if (client.connect(clientID, mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) {
      client.subscribe(mqtt_topic_sub);
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
  }
}


void loop() {
  // Update button state
  // This needs to be called so that the Bouncer object can check if the button has been pressed
  bouncer.update();

  if (bouncer.rose()) {
    // Turn light on when button is pressed down
    // (i.e. if the state of the button rose from 0 to 1 (not pressed to pressed))
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    if (!client.connected()) {
    Connect();
    }
    // PUBLISH to the MQTT Broker (topic = mqtt_topic, defined at the beginning)
    // Here, "Button pressed!" is the Payload, but this could be changed to a sensor reading, for example.
    if (client.publish(mqtt_topic, "Button pressed!")) {
      Serial.println("Button pushed and message sent!");
    }
    // Again, client.publish will return a boolean value depending on whether it succeded or not.
    // If the message failed to send, we will try again, as the connection may have broken.
    else {
      Serial.println("Message failed to send. Reconnecting to MQTT Broker and trying again");
      client.connect(clientID, mqtt_username, mqtt_password);
      delay(10); // This delay ensures that client.publish doesn't clash with the client.connect call
      client.publish(mqtt_topic, "Button pressed!");
    }
  }
  else if (bouncer.fell()) {
    // Turn light off when button is released
    // i.e. if state goes from high (1) to low (0) (pressed to not pressed)
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  client.loop();
}
```